# Confused about the usage of AKSettings

Tags: audiokit

I am quite new to iOS programming, SwiftUI and our beloved AudioKit, so I ran into a problem that seems impossible to solve - but maybe is an easy newbie thing for you more advanced developers.

I need my app to play sound, regardless of whether the iOS device is in silent mode with the dedicated hardware switch. I found in several older postings that the following line is helping to achieve the behaviour I am looking for:

`AKSettings.playbackWhileMuted = true`

But calling this lets my XCode complain "Cannot find 'AKSettings' in scope".
I managed to start the AudioKit engine, and even my DynamicOscillator makes some noise, so AudioKit is there and running but how do I access these settings?

There seems to be no documentation regarding these settings, and I did not find anything in the AudioKit docs, so I feel a little helpless...

Comment: `AKSettings` is now `Settings`, but doesn't have a `playbackWhileMuted` property. My guess (just a guess) is that now you manipulate `AVAudioSession` directly: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/categoryoptions/1616462-defaulttospeaker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not in the AudioKit docs because it is a part of AVFoundation. Like @jnpdx said you set the AVAudioSession directly. There is an example in the AudioKit Cookbook [here](https://github.com/AudioKit/Cookbook/blob/9d356958d414ce097a7ab0e35e679f50be3b9dc4/Cookbook/Cookbook/CookbookApp.swift). The part you want to use is `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback`